# C# Deedle AggregateRowsBy/PivotTable Examples

Tags: c#, f#, data-manipulation, deedle

I am a newbie to C#/F#. There are very limited online resources demonstrating how to aggregate data by group with Deedle in C#. F# format doesn't apply directly in C#.

Data is **Titanic.csv**, from here:
https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/rdataset/source/tree/master/csv/datasets/Titanic.csv

```
var titanic = Frame.ReadCsv(@"Titanic.csv");
#How to proceed, to get the sum of Column Freq?
var res = titanic.AggregateRowsBy<string,string>("Sex","Age",...);
#or
var res = titanic.PivotTable<string,string>("Sex","Age",...);
```

Any simple examples will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: what result do you want to get?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I would like to sum Column freq by groups SEX and AGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume I understand what you want to get. C# code would be as follows:

```
        Frame<string, string> res =
            titanic.PivotTable<int, string, string, string, int>
            ("Sex", "Age", x => x.GetColumn<int>("Freq").NumSum());
```

For your file I get the following results:

```
          Child Adult
Male   -> 64    1667
Female -> 45    425
```